# Python use the old version of OpenSSL (without homebrew)?

Tags: macos, python, openssl

I used macOS Sierra 10.12.6. I DON'T USE HOMEBREW! I tried to download from Vimeo with youtube-dl and got this:

```
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)> (caused by URLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)'),))
```

It's because OpenSSL version supplied with macOS out of date. So I updated openssl like this:

```
$ curl -O https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1b.tar.gz
 $ tar -zxvf openssl-1.1.1b.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-1.1.1b
 $ ./config
 $ make
 $ sudo make install
```

After that, I check openssl version:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1b 26 Feb 2019
```

And check where is it:

```
$ which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl
```

But error exists anyway. Then I check what version python used:

```
$ python -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

It's old out of date version!

Question: how can I tell the python (and other apps that may use openssl) use the new version?

p.s. the python version is:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
```